# react-select: Is it possible to add animated components and custom components simultaneously?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm wondering if it is possible to add animated components and custom components simultaneously in a `components` prop inside a `Select` component.
Couldn't find anything in the react-select documentation, unfortunately.

With "animated components" I'm referring to these: https://react-select.com/home#animated-components.

"Custom components" would be these: https://react-select.com/components#replaceable-components

In my case the custom component would be this one:

```
// Custom component
const CustomMultiValue = (
    props: MultiValueProps<FilterOptions, GroupTypeBase<FilterOptions>>
  ) => (
    <components.MultiValue {...props}>{props.data.label}</components.MultiValue>
  );

// Animated components
  const animatedComponents = makeAnimated();
```

The `Select` looks like this:

```
<Select
      isMulti
      onChange={(value) => handleChange(value)}
      styles={customSelectStyles}
      components={{ MultiValue: CustomMultiValue }}
      theme={customSelectTheme}
      closeMenuOnSelect={false}
      placeholder={placeholder}
/>
```

I've tried a bunch of ways to add the animatedComponents, but nothing seems to work.
For example:

`components={animatedComponents, { MultiValue: CustomMultiValue }}`

`components={{ MultiValue: CustomMultiValue, Control: animatedComponents }}`

Anyone got an idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that what you want is customize your MultiValue component in order to make it animated.

You can see in the documentation for animated components that `makeAnimated` method create a wrapper for components passed as arguments and:

`If no arguments are passed, built-in components are wrapped instead.`

In your code this is the built-in MultiValue component that will be animated

If this is what you want you have to pass you custom MultiValue as argument to `makeAnimated` and use `animatedComponents` in the `components` props of Select

```
// Animated components
  const animatedComponents = makeAnimated({ MultiValue: CustomMultiValue });

...

<Select
      isMulti
      components={animatedComponents}
      ...
/>
```

You can try it in this code sandbox where the MultiValue is animated and customized to display a custom label

https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-payne-ehi8t?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Hey gorazu! Thanks for the solid answer, I appreciate it!
This solution works fine in the codesandbox, in my project however it does not work.
Not sure why exactly. 

Comment: Update: I don't know why exactly, but I just noticed it works now.
Thanks  a bunch @gorazu !

Comment: Nice ! Happy that it helped you 